# How to send heartbeats / ping over django channels 1

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels, daphne

We have [Django Channels](https://github.com/django/channels) running with Daphne and redis.
Before we had [django-websocket-redis](https://github.com/jrief/django-websocket-redis) running and it supports a heartbeat (ping) message out of the box. Our client code depends on this heartbeat to confirm an active connection, but in django we don't really care if it is still active or not.

Because of this we don't need to keep track of everything server side but we do need to send the heartbeat.

How do I send a heartbeat / ping message using channels or daphne? I can't find any docs on this.

The old implementation with django-websocket-redis just sends a websocket message `"--heartbeat--"` every n seconds. [docs reference](http://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/heartbeats.html)

I have read Daphne sends pings but I haven't seen them show up anywhere, my websocket connection just stays open.

Comment: not sure if you've seen this https://github.com/django/channels/issues/563

Comment: No not yet but I just confirm the state of the connection on the client side now. Much easier. And I put an external timer in place for the legacy versions of our app.

Comment: @ThaJay would you mind detailing a bit of information on how you went about doing so?

Comment: the client sends the heartbeat message and it gets echoed back

Comment: @HassenPy hello from 2020 fellow developer!:) I don't see in my chrome developer console how daphne sends out hearbeats and if I should implement something on the frontend to reply to them...

Comment: Maybe this can be of interest?
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/10/firefoxs-new-websocket-inspector/

Comment: Daphne sends keep-alive pings (see 0.10.1 2016-03-29):  https://github.com/django/daphne/blob/e480917c1a68baf9beb5d8b61981750c4e49dcb0/CHANGELOG.txt